# Верстка. Изменение содержимого блока при наведении

Tags: вёрстка

Добрый вечер! Очень нужна помощь. Не знаю как реализовать данный функционал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как при наведении мышки на блок, изменить отображение содержимого.
При наведении, левый блок должен отображаться как правый.

```css
.about__our-team {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.about__our-team__item_1,
.about__our-team__item_2,
.about__our-team__item_3,
.about__our-team__item_4 {
  flex-basis: 250px;
  min-height: 398px;
  background-color: rgba(77, 63, 75, 0.5);
}

h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: #9ec36b;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
}

.our-team__image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #a1859e;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 154px;
  height: 154px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__our-team__item_2">
  <div class="our-team__image"></div>
  <h4>kiril donchev</h4>
  <p>Design Master</p>
  <div class="soc_icon flex">
    <div class="soc_icon-item_1"></div>
    <div class="soc_icon-item_2"></div>
    <div class="soc_icon-item_3"></div>
    <div class="soc_icon-item_4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот стили уже готового блока. Не хватает только бэкграундом добавить соц иконки в нижние дивы и изображение на белый фон. При наведении нужно изменить бордер на красный,

на красный цвет, изображение на красный и придать цвет иконкам.

Comment: добавить в блок элемент, который при наведении только будет показываться. И туда инфу запихнут. Не надо изменять содержимое, просто показывать второй блок который без наведения скрыт.

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать это кодом? Я в верстке недавно, не совсем понимаю как сделать разметку в HTML

Comment: @TrofimchikVlad, киньте ссылку на стили или сюда загрузите и я покажу. Ещё скажите, на какие стили должны изменятся при наведении

Comment: @Yuri, добавил стили в сообщение.

Comment: @TrofimchikVlad, у вас немного стили не соответствуют по картинка. Ну то ладно. Сделайте `.about__our-team__item_2:hover h4 {...}`, `.about__our-team__item_2:hover .soc_icon-item_1 {...}`. Так меняете все нужные стили.

Comment: @Yuri, то есть достаточно изменить стили каждого элемента при наведении и они одновременно все изменятся при наведении курсора в любую точку блока?

Comment: @TrofimchikVlad, я добавил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для изменения при наведении на родителя существует специальная запись. `родитель:hover дочерний_элемент {...}`

```css
.about__our-team {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.about__our-team__item_1,
.about__our-team__item_2,
.about__our-team__item_3,
.about__our-team__item_4 {
  flex-basis: 250px;
  min-height: 398px;
  background-color: rgba(77, 63, 75, 0.5);
}

h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #a1859e;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color 0.5s; /* Добавляем плавность */
}
/* Эффект при наведении */
.about__our-team__item:hover h4 {color: #fff;}

p {
  color: #9ec36b;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color 0.5s; /* Добавляем плавность */
}
/* Эффект при наведении */
.about__our-team__item:hover p {color: #de5b63;}

.our-team__image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #a1859e;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 154px;
  height: 154px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  transition: color 0.5s; /* Добавляем плавность */
}
/* Эффект при наведении */
.about__our-team__item:hover .our-team__image {border-color: #de5b63;}
```

```html
<div class="about__our-team__item_2 about__our-team__item">
  <div class="our-team__image"></div>
  <h4>kiril donchev</h4>
  <p>Design Master</p>
  <div class="soc_icon flex">
    <div class="soc_icon-item_1"></div>
    <div class="soc_icon-item_2"></div>
    <div class="soc_icon-item_3"></div>
    <div class="soc_icon-item_4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Очень помогли))

Comment: @TrofimchikVlad, можете принять мой ответ, чтобы другие пользователи знали, что вам помогло :)